# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'try' (T_TRY) in E:\wamp64\www\project-trial\install.php on line 10

Tags: php, html, pdo, try-catch

I am trying to install the database for my project with this file - install.php
Code Below:

```
<?php
/*
** Open a connection with the database via PDO to create a new database and 
tables with structure & insert initial values.
*/

require "config.php"
/*
** CREATING DATABASE CONNECTION**
*/
try{
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host", $username, $password, $options);
   $sql = file_get_contents("data/init.sql");
   $conn->exec($sql);
   echo "Databse and Tables created successfully. :)";
}catch(PDOException $error){
   echo $sql."<br>".$error->getMessage();
}
?>
```

If I remove the try...catch implementation. Then it shows error unexpected $conn.
Has this anything to do with the PDO object creation. Wouldn't PDO run with
PHP 5.6.35. I am using WAMP 3.0.

Comment: Should be closed as a simple typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `;` at end of line

```
require "config.php";
```

Comment: When the answer is "add one missing semicolon", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a semicolon after require 'config.php'

Comment: When the answer is "add one missing semicolon", there is no need to answer. Just leave a comment under the question and flag/vote to close as Off-topic: Typo. This page will be quickly scrubbed from the site (as will any upvote points you receive) because this page is completely useless to researchers.

Comment: Can't leave comment to question unless 50 rep